# Facebook warm up challenge that I can't seem to figure out - Battleship

Tags: java, algorithm, probability, bigdecimal

I am working on [this MetaCareers code challenge](https://www.metacareers.com/profile/coding_puzzles/?puzzle=3641006936004915&source=careers%3A%2Fresume%2Fresponse%2F) (needs an account):

> You're playing Battleship on a grid of cells with  rows and  columns. There are 0 or more battleships on the grid, each occupying a single distinct cell. The cell in the <sup>th</sup> row from the top and <sup>th</sup> column from the left either contains a battleship (<sub>,</sub>​=1) or doesn't (<sub>,</sub>​=0).
>
> You're going to fire a single shot at a random cell in the grid. You'll choose this cell uniformly at random from the ∗ possible cells. You're interested in the probability that the cell hit by your shot contains a battleship.
>
> Your task is to implement the function `getHitProbability(R, C, G)` which returns this probability.
>
> *Note: Your return value must have an absolute or relative error of at most* 10<sup>─6</sup> *to be considered correct.*
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - 1 ≤ , ≤ 100
> - 0 ≤ <sub>,</sub>​ ≤ 1
>
> #### Sample test case #1
>
> ```
> R = 2
> C = 3
> G = 0 0 1
>     1 0 1
> ```
>
> ```
> Expected Return Value = 0.50000000
> ```
>
> #### Sample test case #2
>
> ```
> R = 2
> C = 2
> G = 1 1
>     1 1
> ```
>
> ```
> Expected Return Value = 1.00000000
> ```
>
> #### Sample Explanation
>
> In the first case, 3 of the 6 cells in the grid contain battleships. Therefore, the probability that your shot will hit one of them is 3 / 6 = 0.5.
>
> In the second case, all 4 cells contain battleships, resulting in a probability of 1.0 of hitting a battleship.

So it seems clear that the probability = ships / grid_size

And I'm rounding it to the 8<sup>th</sup> decimal -- which I can't seem to get right.... What is my mistake?

My code attempt:

```java
if (G.length == 0) return 0;
double ships = 0.00000000;
for (int[] i : G) {
    if (i[0] == 1) ships++;
}
float ans = Math.round((ships / (float) G.length) * 100000000) / 100000000.0f;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(ans));
String ans = String.format("%.8f", (ships / G.length));
// System.out.println(ans);
// BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(ships/G.length);
// System.out.println(bd1);
```

Comment: You should test your code for acase when rouding is important e.g. `1 1 1\0 0 0\0 0 0 `

Comment: is rounding even needed? isn't it actually counterproductive? maybe the problem is more like is `double` and `float` able to represent such a precision

Comment: You could have a look at [how to post code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: Sorry, I know the code look like crap. StackOverflow wasn't letting me save edit so I went to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the issues in your code attempt:

- It only looks at the first column of the given grid -- with `i[0]` -- not considering that there might be ships at `i[1]`, `i[2]`, ...etc.
- It miscalculates the total number of cells in the grid, as `G.length` represents the number of *rows*, not taking into account the number of *columns*. The total number of cells is `G.length * G[0].length`.
- It attempts to redefine the variable `ans` which will not allow the code to compile.
- It does not execute a `return` after having defined `ans`.
- It converts a calculated value to `String`, while the return type of the function is `double`.

Not a real problem, but:

- It attempts to round a value to 8 decimal digits, but this is not necessary, as that will only make the answer *less* accurate.
- It deals with the case where the grid is empty, but this case will never happen, as  and  are guaranteed to be at least 1.
- Instead of testing the value of the cell, you could just add the cell's value to the `ships` value, given that the cell's value is guaranteed to be 0 or 1 and adding 0 leaves the value of `ships` unchanged.

Here is the correction of your code as a spoiler:

> `public double getHitProbability(int R, int C, int[][] G) {
>     double ships = 0;
>     for (int[] row : G) {
>         for (int val : row) {  // Visit each cell in the row
>             ships += val; // Add the cell's value unconditionally
>         }
>     }
>     return ships / (G.length * G[0].length); // The total number of cells is R*C
>   }`

Comment: Holy shit. Brain went to shit last night. You're right! Thank you kind stranger!

Comment: Accepted. The 2 sample cases were deceptive. It let me keep thinking that ships/G.length was acceptable. Don't LC with alcohol, I didn't realize that wasn't giving me the length of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Python Solution:

```
def getHitProbability(R: int, C: int, G: List[List[int]]) -> float:
    total = R*C
    cells = sum(sum(row) for row in G)
    probability = cells/total
    return probability
```

You can count the number of cells with the battleships and divide it by the total number of cells in the grid.

Comment: The question is tagged `java`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript/Node Solution: (and also it's much easier to just use R * C for totalCells versus doing (R.length * R[0].length)

```
/**
 * @param {number} R
 * @param {number} C
 * @param {number[][]} G
 * @return {number}
 */
function getHitProbability(R, C, G) {
  // Write your code here
  const totalCells = R * C;
  let cellsWithShipsCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < G.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < G[i].length; j++) {
      cellsWithShipsCount += G[i][j];
    }
  }
  return cellsWithShipsCount / totalCells;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged `java`.